# Adding a notification bar to a website

Tags: html, notifications

I want to add a red notification bar to my site to display notices for example scheduled maintenance.

What code would I need to add to my site to enable this to work.

Thanks.

Comment: I want a pony and a unicorn. So what's your question?

Comment: My bad. Need coffee. What would the code need to be to add something like this to my website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a div with some styling to the top of your site.

```
<div id="notificationbar">
    <p>Currently the site is down</p>
</div>
```

You can style it with css:

```
#notificationbar {
    background-color: red;
}

#notificationbar p {
    color: white;
}
```

You can do many things with it using javascript or css. If you don't understand the above, you should check out how to write HTML and CSS (try looking on google) or hire someone who does.

Comment: Welcome, don't forget to click the green checkmark.

Comment: Thanks for that. Will do as soon as 5 mins has passed. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem. Welcome to StackOverflow, however do try using google first...

Comment: How do you make this box scale the entire width of the page?

Comment: @StephenKuehl Depends on your scenario. But first just try setting `#notificationbar { width: 100%; }`. If you're using `position: fixed;` it should work with just that. If your position is not fixed, then it will scale to `100%` of the parent, then just make sure that the parent is `100%` of the page. If you notice that it doesn't quite reach the edges make sure that the body of the page has `margin:0;` and also the `#notificationbar`. Just fiddle around in the dev tools until you get it looking right.